# Regex pattern for extracting follower count

Tags: python, regex

I am extracting the follower numbers from a string such as the one below. The first pattern doesn't seem to work on single digits. Is it because the first pattern checks if there's a character after the digit and the first line has no other characters between `4` and `Followers`? The second pattern works just fine.

```
import re

text = """
4 Followers
330 Followers
23.5k Followers
67k Followers
25m Followers
"""
print(re.compile(r'(\d.+) Followers').findall(text))
print(re.compile(r'(\d+|\d.+) Followers').findall(text))
```

Comment: You should really simply use https://regex101.com/

Comment: Just split the space and get the first array..

Comment: @Idos That what I've used. Just new to regex and trying to understand the pattern I've come up with better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\d.+` pattern matches a digit and then 1 or more chars other than line break chars.

It seems you want to match a digit and then anything other than whitespace up to a whitespace followed with `Followers`.

Use

```
text = """
4 Followers
330 Followers
23.5k Followers
67k Followers
25m Followers
"""
print(re.findall(r'\b(\d\S*) Followers', text))
# => ['4', '330', '23.5k', '67k', '25m']
```

See the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/1iiIEk/2) and [Python demo](https://ideone.com/ajHCs4).

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(\d\S*)` - Group 1: a digit, and then 0+ non-whitespace symbols
- `Followers` - a literal substring.

If your input is formatted well, you may also split the strings:

```
[x.split()[0] for x in text.split('\n')]
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Gksvyl) (output: `['4', '330', '23.5k', '67k', '25m']`).

Comment: I'll go with the pattern as the `text` string was just used as a dummy, the pattern is used to extract the follower count from a scraped website, regex just so happened to be a lot faster than bs4. Solid answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

*I believe your question is why the different results with the 2 patterns...*

It's not that the first pattern doesn't match single digits, it's that
the first pattern expects a digit followed by 2 characters before `Followers`.

I don't see any *ignore whitespace modifier* associated with the regex,
so the regex is really

```
                                  (\d.+)[ ]Followers  
                                     ^   ^
          where this ----------------|   |  
          expects at least 1 char,       |
          and this ----------------------|
          expects 1 more
          ===================================
             total is minimum 2 chars between digit and Followers
```

The reason the *second* regex works is it expects only 1 character
between the digit and Followers

```
                      (\d+|\d.+)[ ]Followers
                        ^        ^
              digit ----|        |
              1 char-------------|
```